# What is Good way to get Related Content

Tags: php, mysql

What's good method to fetch related content in php. i have $keyword, if i use in where title LIKE '%$keyword%' it returns same.my method is simple like:

```
$keywords = 'Most Perfectly Timed Videos EVER';
$rel = mysql_query("select * from media where title LIKE '%$keywords%'")or
die(mysql_error());
```

I want max result relevant my keyword.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM media WHERE ";
$keywords = 'Most Perfectly Timed Videos EVER';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
$where = "";
foreach($keywords as $k => $v)
{
    $where .= "title LIKE '%".$v."%' AND ";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, -5); //deleting the last "AND"

$query .= $where;
$rel = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

or, if you might want to use "OR" instead of "AND" for better results:

```
foreach($keywords as $k => $v)
{
    $where .= "title LIKE '%".$v."%' OR ";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, -4);
```